# How do I prevent SQLite3 from auto incrementing to same value twice?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I have found that SQLite3's auto incrementation is always one more than the highest existing primary key.

For instance I create a record and its id is set to 1. Then the next record's id is set to 2. If I delete the record with id = 2 and create a new record, the new one's id is set to 2, instead of 3.

Is their anyway to have the auto increment of sqlite3 never assign the same value twice?

Comment: Why are you hard deleting rows from your DB?  You should just soft-delete them and never have this issue, plus you never lose your data in case you would need to roll something back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs at http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html clearly state that the behavior you are seeing is expected. The docs also state that you avoid this issue by making the column:

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```